# DPI higher than 150%

Tags: windows-7

I have my HTPC on my TV, however I want to have the DPI at about 200% instead of the largest value (GUI wise).

Is it possible (either by a third party app, reg key or something else) to have the DPI larger than 150%?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the display control panel, where you're seeing the choices small (100), medium (125) and large (150), look at the list of links on the far left. The bottom choice "set custom text size (DPI)" takes you to a screen where you can enter whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot!.. It really helps with Virtual machines with 4K display where you don't want to scale your screen but still want guest OS to be bit bigger. Otherwise fonts will be much more smaller to read!

Comment: Literally no other site on the web seems to have this answer for Windows 7.